# Swagger not working have any recommerndation?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

Not working Swagger Ui

500 : {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Invalid type owner for DynamicMethod.","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException","StackTrace":" at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.Init(String name, MethodAttributes attributes, CallingConventions callingConvention, Type returnType, Type[] signature, Type owner, Module m, Boolean skipVisibility, Boolean transparentMethod, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)\r\n at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod..ctor(String name, Type returnType, Type[] parameterTypes, Type owner, Boolean skipVisibility)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DynamicReflectionDelegateFactory.CreateDynamicMethod(String name, Type returnType, Type[] parameterTypes, Type owner)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Utilities.DynamicReflectionDelegateFactory.CreateDefaultConstructor[T](Type type)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.GetDefaultCreator(Type createdType)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.InitializeContract(JsonContract contract)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateArrayContract(Type objectType)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.CreateContract(Type objectType)\r\n at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContract(Type type)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SchemaRegistry.CreateInlineSchema(Type type)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SchemaRegistry.GetOrRegister(Type type)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.CreateParameter(String location, ApiParameterDescription paramDesc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass12.b__11(ApiParameterDescription paramDesc)\r\n at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2.MoveNext()\r\n at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)\r\n at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.CreateOperation(ApiDescription apiDesc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.CreatePathItem(IEnumerable`1 apiDescriptions, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass7.<GetSwagger>b__4(IGrouping`2 group)\r\n at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector, IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Swagger.SwaggerGenerator.GetSwagger(String rootUrl, String apiVersion)\r\n at Swashbuckle.Application.SwaggerDocsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Net.Http.HttpMessageInvoker.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpRoutingDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n at System.Web.Http.HttpServer.d__0.MoveNext()"} http://localhost:5352/swagger/docs/v1

Comment: Provide your app start, your services and generally any configuration related to swagger with code.

Comment: What version of Swashbuckle do you use?

Comment: 5.6 version I use

Answer (score 3):

When I got this error, it was because I had an error/omission in my ResponseType definition (WebApi). The compiler was fine with it, but Swagger wasn't.

Failed

```
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<>))]
```

Worked

```
[ResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<string>))]
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having this error with Swashbuckle

```
Invalid type owner for DynamicMethod
```

For my case it was caused by having a class A inherited by a constraint-less class B

```cs
public class A
{
}

public class B<T> : A 
{
     public T MyWrongProp { get; set; } // <- ❌ wrong
}
```

In conjuction with `UseOneOfForPolymorphism` (might be something different for you)

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
{
    x.UseOneOfForPolymorphism();
});
```

I guess the issue is that Swashbuckle scans for all types, and finds `B<T>` because it inherits `A` and it is then trying to do something with `T` which is undefined.

### How to fix this

The short anwser is to strip `B'1 (B<T>)` from the generation and assign `B<T>` a default generic type:

```cs
public class B : B<MyDefaultGenericType>
{
}
```

```cs
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(x =>
{
    x.UseOneOfForPolymorphism();
    x.SelectSubTypesUsing(baseType =>
    {
        if (baseType == typeof(ValueType))
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<Type>();
        }

        var types = baseType.Assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(baseType))
            .Where(
                t => !t.IsGenericType || t.GenericTypeArguments.ElementAtOrDefault(0) != default
            );

        return types;
    });
});
```